# How to make seprate js file for vue.js operation in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

hi in my project i am using test.js file to define the vue functionality instead of using app.js file for all operation i have included vue.min.js file in my project when i try to use

```
**import UploadForm from '/components/UploadForm.vue';** this is showing the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
  var data = {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
}

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    delimiters: ['{%', '%}'],
    data: data,
    components:{UploadForm}
});


Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div>A custom component! anil kumar sahu</div>'
})

// create a root instance
new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})
```

when i remove the import UploadForm from '/components/UploadForm.vue'; it is running successfully

Comment: You would probably be better off using something like  `Vue.component('upload-form', require('./components/UploadForm.vue'));`

Comment: In order to use "import" statements, you have to use loaders like babel, i.e. compile those es2015 statements to javascript.